# Using rvest to extract data from dropbox tabs where is the data is stored as HTML options

Tags: r, rvest

I have the following website which contains drop-down boxes for a number of different regions.

```
url <- "https://catsalut.gencat.cat/ca/centres-sanitaris/cercador/"
```

I would like get a dataframe which would look like the following:

```
Regió Sanitària                Comarca       Municipi
ALT PIRINEU i ARAN             Alt Urgel      Alàs I Cerc
ALT PIRINEU i ARAN             Alt Urgel      Arsèguel
ALT PIRINEU i ARAN             Alt Urgel      Bassella
ALT PIRINEU i ARAN               ...             ...

... 

ALT PIRINEU i ARAN          Alta Ribagorça   Pont De suert
ALT PIRINEU i ARAN          Alta Ribagorça   Vall De Boí
ALT PIRINEU i ARAN          Alta Ribagorça   Vilaller

...

Barcelona                   Alt Pendès       Avinyonet Del Penedès
Barcelona                   Alt Pendès       Cabanyes

....

Camp de Tarragona            Alt Camp         Aiguamúrcia

...
```

So, from the drop-down boxes I would like to have a data frame of all the `Municipis` in a `Comarca` for all `Regió Sanitària`.

For the `Regió Sanitària` we have the following options in the HTML code:

```
<option value="0">-- Seleccioni una regió --</option>
<option value="71">Alt Pirineu i Aran</option>
<option value="78">Barcelona</option>
<option value="62">Camp de Tarragona</option>
<option value="67">Catalunya Central</option>
<option value="64">Girona</option>
<option value="61">Lleida</option>
<option value="63">Terres de l'Ebre</option>
```

Then in the `Comarca` dropdown box we have the following:

```
<option value="0">-- Seleccioni una comarca --</option>
<option value="01">Alt Camp</option><option value="02">Alt Empordà</option><option value="03">Alt Penedès</option><option value="04">Alt Urgell</option><option value="05">Alta Ribagorça</option><option value="06">Anoia</option><option value="07">Bages</option><option value="08">Baix Camp</option><option value="09">Baix Ebre</option><option value="10">Baix Empordà</option><option value="11">Baix Llobregat</option><option value="12">Baix Penedès</option><option value="13">Barcelonès</option><option value="14">Berguedà</option><option value="15">Cerdanya</option><option value="16">Conca de Barberà</option><option value="17">Garraf</option><option value="18">Garrigues</option><option value="19">Garrotxa</option><option value="20">Gironès</option><option value="21">Maresme</option><option value="42">Moianes</option><option value="22">Montsià</option><option value="23">Noguera</option><option value="24">Osona</option><option value="25">Pallars Jussà</option><option value="26">Pallars Sobirà</option><option value="27">Pla d'Urgell</option><option value="28">Pla de l'Estany</option><option value="29">Priorat</option><option value="30">Ribera d'Ebre</option><option value="31">Ripollès</option><option value="32">Segarra</option><option value="33">Segrià</option><option value="34">Selva</option><option value="35">Solsonès</option><option value="36">Tarragonès</option><option value="37">Terra Alta</option><option value="38">Urgell</option><option value="39">Vall d'Aran</option><option value="40">Vallès Occidental</option><option value="41">Vallès Oriental</option>
```

Opening the `inspect element` tab and selecting `Barcelona` and then `Maresme` I can see under the `Municipi` HMTL `<option value="...">` code the numbers and place names change (if it is possible to keep these numbers also).

EDIT:

This doesn't work:

```
catSalutCentros <- "https://catsalut.gencat.cat/ca/centres-sanitaris/cercador/"

x <- catSalutCentros %>% 
  read_html()

x %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath="//option[@selected]") %>%
  html_text()

x %>% 
  html_nodes("option") %>%
  html_text()

[1] "-- Seleccioni una regió --"   "-- Seleccioni una comarca --" "-- Seleccioni un municipi --"
```

EDIT 2:

Running:

```
> x %>% 
+   html_nodes("option")
{xml_nodeset (3)}
[1] <option value="0">-- Seleccioni una regió --</option>
[2] <option value="0">-- Seleccioni una comarca --</option>
[3] <option value="0">-- Seleccioni un municipi --</option>
```

So, could would it be feasible to create a function to `map` over and change the option value to the unique option values given in the `Regió Sanitària` part of the HTML code. Then `map` over the unique option values in the `comarca` part - changing the `<option value ="x">` part of the HTML code and storing them that way?

Comment: You won't be able to use rvest for this goal as the data is loaded dynamically on click. It's stored [here](https://catsalut.gencat.cat/web/.content/xml/out.xml) in a neatly structured XML that is easy to parse to a data frame.